# Using python to move jp2 image to MySql Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, image, blob, mysql-python

I am currently using Python with MySQLdb to edit some MySQL Workbench tables. I was able to move some png images from my computer to the table under the data type "Blob" But this does not work for my larger(1-5 gigabyte) jp2 images. How would I go about moving those up to a MySQL table?